# google play services ad is displaying in corner in android

Tags: android, xcode, cocos2d-x

I have developed a game in xcode using cocos2d-x & converted to android.Then i added google play services ad, but it is displaying in leftsidecorner. I want to display it in the middle.
Please anyone help me to find the solution.

```
private Point getDisplaySize(Display d)
{
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
     {
        return getDisplaySizeGE11(d);
     }
     return getDisplaySizeLT11(d);
 }
 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
 private Point getDisplaySizeGE11(Display d)
 {
     Point p = new Point(0, 1);
     d.getSize(p);
     return p;
 }
 private Point getDisplaySizeLT11(Display d)
 {
  try
  {
    Method getWidth = Display.class.getMethod("getWidth", new Class[] {}); 
    Method getHeight = Display.class.getMethod("getHeight", new Class[] {});
    return new Point(((Integer) getWidth.invoke(d,(Object[]) null)).intValue(),                               
    ((Integer) getHeight.invoke(d, (Object[]) null)).intValue());
  }
    catch (NoSuchMethodException e2) // None of these exceptions should ever occur.
     {
         return new Point(-1, -1);
     }
     catch (IllegalArgumentException e2)
     {
         return new Point(-2, -2);
     }
     catch (IllegalAccessException e2)
     {
         return new Point(-3, -3);
     }
     catch (InvocationTargetException e2)
     {
         return new Point(-4, -4);
     }
  }
         @Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    int width = getDisplaySize(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()).y;
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);


   AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
  .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
  .addTestDevice("HASH_DEVICE_ID")
  .build();
  adView.loadAd(adRequest);
  adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
  adView.setBackgroundColor(0);
  addContentView(adView,adParams);
  _appActiviy = this;
  }
```

Comment: I am not using any layout. I am using only google play services ad code in .java file.

Comment: If you're displaying anything, you're using a layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your above code make the following changes.

Find the below code

```
adParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
```

Change it as follows

```
adParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.BOTTOM;
```

Then the add will display in middle of your Application bottom.